# Computation within a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, loops, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
wt
Out[189]: 
[defaultdict(int,
             {'A01': 0.15,
              'A02': 0.17,
              'A03': 0.13,
              'A04': 0.17,
              'A05': 0.01,
              'A06': 0.12,
              'A07': 0.15,
              'A08': 0.0,
              'A09': 0.02,
              'A10': 0.09}),
 defaultdict(int,
             {'A01': 0.02,
              'A02': 0.02,
              'A03': 0.06,
              'A04': 0.08,
              'A05': 0.08,
              'A06': 0.04,
              'A07': 0.02,
              'A08': 0.24,
              'A09': 0.34,
              'A10': 0.1}),
 defaultdict(int,
             {'A01': 0.0,
              'A02': 0.12,
              'A03': 0.01,
              'A04': 0.01,
              'A05': 0.11,
              'A06': 0.13,
              'A07': 0.1,
              'A08': 0.36,
              'A09': 0.13,
              'A10': 0.03})]
```

And I have another dictionary:

```
zz
Out[188]: defaultdict(int, {'S1': 0.44, 'S2': 0.44, 'S3': 0.12})
```

I need to run a loop to aggregate the following computation:

```
'S1':0.44 * 'A01':0.15 + 'S2':0.44 * 'A01':0.02 + 'S3':0.12 * 'A01':0.00 ----- to be stored in a dict with the key 'A01'
'S1':0.44 * 'A02':0.17 + 'S2':0.44 * 'A02':0.02 + 'S3':0.12 * 'A02':0.12 ----- to be stored in a dict with the key 'A02'
.
.
.and so on upto:
'S1':0.44 * 'A10':0.09 + 'S2':0.44 * 'A10':0.1 + 'S3':0.12 * 'A10':0.03 ----- to be stored in a dict with the key 'A10'
```

Can somebody please suggest a loop for this? The issue I'm facing is that:

```
wt[0]
Out[197]: 
defaultdict(int,
            {'A01': 0.15,
             'A02': 0.17,
             'A03': 0.13,
             'A04': 0.17,
             'A05': 0.01,
             'A06': 0.12,
             'A07': 0.15,
             'A08': 0.0,
             'A09': 0.02,
             'A10': 0.09})
```

But:

```
wt[0][0]
Out[199]: 0
```

I'm not being able to access each value within the dict.

Comment: Which value were you expecting `wt[0][0]` to give you? There's no key `0`, so you get the default value generated by `int` (which seems like an odd choice given that the other values are all `float`, but...). Try e.g. `wt[0]['A01']`.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do matrix multiplication. In that case I recommend you don't use dictionaries, and instead look at numpy or pandas

Comment: Thanks, will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your aggregation with a dict comprehension:

```
x = [defaultdict(int, {'A01': 0.15, 'A02': 0.17, 'A03': 0.13, 'A04': 0.17, 'A05': 0.01, 'A06': 0.12, 'A07': 0.15, 'A08': 0.0, 'A09': 0.02, 'A10': 0.09}), 
     defaultdict(int, {'A01': 0.02, 'A02': 0.02, 'A03': 0.06, 'A04': 0.08, 'A05': 0.08, 'A06': 0.04, 'A07': 0.02, 'A08': 0.24, 'A09': 0.34, 'A10': 0.1}), 
     defaultdict(int, {'A01': 0.0, 'A02': 0.12, 'A03': 0.01, 'A04': 0.01, 'A05': 0.11, 'A06': 0.13, 'A07': 0.1, 'A08': 0.36, 'A09': 0.13, 'A10': 0.03})]
mult = defaultdict(int, {'S1': 0.44, 'S2': 0.44, 'S3': 0.12})

d = {k: sum(d[k] * mult['S'+str(idx+1)] 
     for idx, d in enumerate(x)) for k in x[0].keys()}
```

If you want to multiply your matrix with a vector, you should try numpy:

```
import numpy as np

# Transform data to matrix
x = np.array([[d['A'+str(i+1).zfill(2)] for i in range(len(d))] for d in x])
v = np.array([mult['S'+str(i+1)] for i in range(len(mult))]).reshape(1, 3)

print(np.matmul(v, x))
# [[0.0748 0.098  0.0848 0.1112 0.0528 0.086  0.0868 0.1488 0.174  0.0872]]
```